# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, poo

Estoy aprendiendo poo en python y estoy intentando restarle a una variable el precio de un producto al eliminarlo de un diccionario, el caso es que me dice que el valor que devuelve a partir del map.get(producto) es NoneType.

Por otro lado he hecho un diccionario aparte y he comprobado el tipo de valor que me devuelve a partir de una key, pero me sale bien, dice que es de tipo float.[image: Código con el que estoy trabajando, me da el fallo en la linea que estoy señalando con el cursor]

```py
   class shop():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.products = {}
        self.total = 0.0

    def add_item(self,product,price):
        if product in self.products:
            print("Item's already in the list")
        else:
            self.products[product] = price
            self.total+=price
            print(product,"has been added to the list")
    
    def remove_item(self,product):
        if product in self.products:
            self.products.pop(product)
            self.total-=self.products.get(product)
            print(product,"has been removed from the list")
        else:
            print("Item's not in the list")

    def getTotal(self):
        return self.total

    def toString(self):
        res = ""

        for i in self.products:
            res+= i + " || "+str(self.products.get(i))+"\n"
        
        res += "-------------\nTOTAL: "+str(self.getTotal())
        return res
```

Comment: Ya estaría, ¡perdón!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta de @Angel está algo bien, sin embargo algo que tiene que saber es que si primero eliminan el ítem del diccionario, ya no habrá referencia a el para poder restarle su valor lo que devuelve un `keyError`,  aplicando los cambios en el aspecto del diccionario como hizo @Angel y añadiendo algunas mejoras el código de `remove_item` quedará asi:

```
def remove_item(self, product):
        found = None
        for i in range(len(self.products)):
           #aqui hay un cambio, se verifica si el producto solicitado se encuentra en la lista 
            if product in self.products:
                found = True
        if found:
            #aqui primero restamos el precio y luego eliminamos el ítem
            self.total -= self.products[product]
            del self.products[product]
            print(product, "has been removed from the list")
        else:
            print("Item's not in the list")
```

Si primero quieres eliminar el producto y luego restarle tendrás que obtener el precio de tal producto y guárdalo en una variable para que así se pueda eliminar, pero sugiero que se haga de la forma en que lo planteo

Answer (score 0):

```
class Shop():
    def __init__(self):
        self.products = {}
        self.total = 0.0

    def add_item(self, product, price):
        found = None
        for i in range(len(self.products)):
            if product in self.products.keys():
                found = True
                print("Item's already in the list")
        if not found:
            self.products[product] = price
            self.total += price
            print(product, "has been added to the list")

    def remove_item(self, product):
        found = None
        for i in range(len(self.products)):
            if self.products[product] in self.products.keys():
                found = True
        if found:
            del self.products[product]
            self.total -= self.products[product]
            print(product, "has been removed from the list")
        else:
            print("Item's not in the list")

    def getTotal(self):
        return self.total

    def toString(self):
        res = ""

        for i in self.products:
            res+= i + " || "+str(self.products.get(i))+"\n"
        
        res += "-------------\nTOTAL: "+str(self.total)
        return res

Tienda = Shop()

Tienda.add_item("libro", 10)
print(Tienda.getTotal())
print(Tienda.toString())
#Tienda.remove_item("libro")
```

La función `add_item()` recibe un nombre de producto y un precio y, si esa pareja clave-valor no existe en el diccionario, se añade.

La función `remove_item()` recibe un nombre de producto y lo elimina en caso de que exista

La función `getTotal()` devuelve el total.

La función `toString()` imprime un ticket de compra.

Te faltaba crear un objeto de la clase: `Tienda = Shop()`. Además, he cambiado aspectos relativos a los [diccionarios](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

El error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'float' and 'NoneType'` se debe a que un operando es `float` y el otro tiene el valor `None`. Es debido a que el diccionario está vacío y, por tanto, al acceder a un elemento el valor que devuelve es `None`, pues no existe.

El resultado es:

```
libro has been added to the list
10.0
libro || 10
-------------
TOTAL: 10.0
```

---

**Mejora de presentación**

Modificando la función `toString()`:

```
def toString(self):
    res = ""

    for i in self.products:
        res+= i + " • "+str(self.products.get(i))+"\n"
    
    res += "—————————————\nTOTAL: "+str(self.total)
    return res
```

El resultado es:

```
libro has been added to the list
10.0
libro • 10
—————————————
TOTAL: 10.0
```

Comment: Encontré algunos errores en tu codugo :b, ejecutanto tu codigo me sale que no se enco tro el item cuando si esta